# How can I join tables and save data in Magento?

Tags: database, magento

I have a question in Magento. I have table A with primary key(PK) is `'a_id'` and table B with PK is `'b_id'`. I created table C with 2 foreign keys which are `'a_id'` and `'b_id'.`

I also created model for A and B tables,to save,update,delete...records in them. 
So my question is: how can I save data in table C,**without creating a model for this table**. I searched on the Internet and really confused about join tables.
Can anybody help me? I'm newbie in Magento so step-by-step tutorial will be very helpful.

Thanks a lot. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

After saving data in both table "A" and "B" write following logic, no need of join a table.

```php
$_resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$_tableName = $_resource->getTableName('c');

$write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");

//you need to get primary keys from both tables.
//$a_id,$b_id

$query = "insert into $_tableName"
       . "(a_id, b_id) values "
       . "($a_id, $b_id)";

$write->query($query);
```